# Books recommendation for dynamic programming

Tags: book-recommendation, dynamic-programming

Good time of the day!
I have some math background and I would like to learn dynamic programming. I know about Bellman's "Dynamic programming", but this book is more then 60 years old. Is this books is still relevant and comprehensive to learn from it? Are there more modern books on dynamic programming?
Thanks.

Comment: You aksed this question previously and then deleted it. This is the exact same question so I expect it will garner the same level of attention.

Comment: This is not the same question. I provided additional details and edited the question according to the guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I see you've added tags.

Comment: @Kevin, this is wrong. The first question had the same tags. I reedited the question.

Answer (score 1):

- Chapter $11$ of [Introduction to Operations Research (10th Edition) by Frederick S. Hillier and Gerald J. Lieberman](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_Operations_Research/LgXfmwEACAAJ?hl=en)

This chapter contains one of the better introductions to Dynamic Programming I have seen yet from any source, and I use it for the first three weeks of class to introduce the subject before diving into [Bellman's book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dynamic_Programming/RpkvEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). Chapter $11$ covers core definitions and Deterministic and Probabilistic properties of Dynamic problems, and its example problems are incredibly well thought out and discussed in detail. Would recommend this chapter alone above all else.

- Chapter 9 of [Operations Research An Introduction (4th Edition) by Hamdy A. Taha](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Operations_Research/2_WJSgAACAAJ?hl=en)

He doesn't have the specific chapter anymore in his newer books, but this is where I first heard/learned about Dynamic Programming, and while it isn't as good as the book above (in that it doesn't necessarily dive into the theory all that well), it makes up this shortcoming by providing a lot of example problems and solutions that can be used to complement the other texts (a lot of my assigned problems come from this chapter).

- [Dynamic Programming: A Computational Tool by Lew and Mauch](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dynamic_Programming/IzlsCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)

This book is dedicated to using Dynamic Programming on a lot of applications (the book has $46$ sections in chapter two, each about a single problem topic alone). This book is one I would highly recommend as one a person would use if they want to explore various problems for research. In addition, the book's hyperlink to the DP2PN2Solver is outdated. I reached out to Dr. Mauch and he provided me with the newer link for the software: [https://natsci.eckerd.edu/~mauchh@campus/Research/indexSoftware.php](https://natsci.eckerd.edu/%7Emauchh@campus/Research/indexSoftware.php)